# Trigonometric curiosity

Tags: trigonometry

How prove this $$-\tan\frac{10\pi}{41}+4\left(\sin\frac{2\pi}{41}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{41}+\sin\frac{12\pi}{41}+\sin\frac{20\pi}{41}-\sin\frac{26\pi}{41}-\sin \frac{30\pi}{41}\right)= \\\cot\frac{2\pi}{41}-\cot\frac{8\pi}{41}+\cot\frac{20\pi}{41}+\cot\frac{32\pi}{41}+\cot\frac{36\pi}{41}$$

Comment: step 1 is to edit your question so that it displays properly.  \frac{numerator}{denominator}, \tan, \sin, and \cos would be a good start.

Comment: Perhaps the complex method?

Comment: for information,by user the complex method,the common value of these relationships is $\sqrt{41+4\sqrt{41}-2\sqrt{533+80\sqrt{41}}}$